# How can I convert a SQL query to an application

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Can I write a program in order to get result from below query instead of writing the same again and again in Toad?

Example:

```
Select 
    cd.id, cd.caseid, c.carriercaseid, c.orderid, ST.name
from 
    gnet.documentt cd
left join 
    gnet.caset c on c.id = cd.caseid
join 
    gnet.tempid ST on ST.ID = C.orderid
where  
    cd.id = 40490517;
```

Where I can only enter " cd.id = XXXXX " and get the result.

Comment: You can define a [view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-B227BBFC-7B6D-400A-AFD7-1E73F1AF1FDB).

Comment: I think you need a Stored Procedure.

Comment: TOAD can prompt for bind variables, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: will try thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If I have understood your question correctly, a simple stored procedure that takes your `cd_id` as an input parameter and runs the desired select statement should work.

Something like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_CD_INFO(my_cd_id IN gnet.documentt.id%TYPE, cd_info OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
 IS
BEGIN

OPEN cd_info FOR
Select 
    cd.id, cd.caseid, c.carriercaseid, c.orderid, ST.name
from 
    gnet.documentt cd
left join 
    gnet.caset c on c.id = cd.caseid
join 
    gnet.tempid ST on ST.ID = c.orderid
where  
    cd.id = GET_CD_INFO.my_cd_id;

END;
```

Which you can call like this...

```
EXECUTE GET_CD_INFO(40490517);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks !! That works too , but on production i am not allowed for any such modification. Any program which only need a click and value i want to enter in order to get the same result?